# Asp.net mvc razor syntax error in if else

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, syntax-error

I spent 2 hours tracing syntax error in below code. What might be the issue

```
<div id="generalError">
    <div>
        @{if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "500")
        {
            <img src="~/Content/Images/oops.png" />
        }
        else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "404")
        {
            <img src="~/Content/Images/sad.png" />
        }
        else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "401")
        {
            <img src="~/Content/Images/authError.png" />
        }
        else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "419" || System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "408")
        {
            <img src="~/Content/Images/oops.png" />
        }
        else
        {
            <img src="~/Content/Images/oops.png" />
        }
        }
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:600px;padding-left:50px;">
        <div style="color:#fff;font-size:36px;font-family:'Segoe UI Light'">
            Sorry, something went wrong.
        </div>
        <div style="color:#fff;font-size:16px;font-family:'Segoe UI';padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:5px;">
            @if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "500")
            {
                @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["errorMessage"].ToString());
            }
            else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "419" || System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "408")
            {
                @: Timeout error.
                }
            else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "404")
            {
                @: Page not found.
            }
            else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "403")
            {
                @: Forbidden.
            }
            else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["statusCode"].ToString() == "401")
            {
                @: Unauthorized error.
                }
            else
            {
                @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["errorMessage"].ToString());
            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: on which line number u get an error

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove "{" between @ and if ...

```
    @{if ==> @if
```